# SQL Server - Range Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need your help to get the below output from the given input.

**Input**

Table: `Sample`

```
ID
---
1
2
3
4
```

**Output**

```
ID
---
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
SELECT ID
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) T(ID)
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 1 N
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE [Type] = 'P'
        AND
        [Number] < T.ID
) TT(V);
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b19518635199183f994077e741cf3ce8)**

> Why using `spt_values` and not a self-join?

In case for example you don't have the value `3`

```
SELECT T.ID
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (4)) T(ID)
INNER JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (4)) TT(ID)
ON T.ID >= TT.ID 
ORDER BY T.ID;
```

The slef-join will repeat the value `4` three times instead of four times.
Using `spt_values` will guarantee that every number will repeated as expected.

```
SELECT T.ID
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (4)) T(ID)
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 1 N
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE [Type] = 'P'
        AND
        [Number] < T.ID
) TT(V);
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54d93d34af0e0a7836989357833ee988)**

---

If you have a lot of numbers, then you can use Tally Table as

```
CREATE VIEW Tally (N) AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 0)) N
FROM (
       (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) T1(N) --10
       CROSS JOIN
       (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) T2(N) --100
       CROSS JOIN
       (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) T3(N) --1000
       CROSS JOIN
       (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) T5(N) --10000
     );
SELECT T.V
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (4), (80), (4000)) T(V)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT N FROM Tally WHERE N <= T.V) TBL
ORDER BY T.V;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7c7d5ba114fdd87810339badd8cb407)

Answer (score 7):

With a self join:

```
select s.id
from sample s inner join sample ss
on s.id >= ss.id 
order by s.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c504af4bbb6061cd8a998d9814220e2).
Results:

```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> |  3 |
> |  3 |
> |  4 |
> |  4 |
> |  4 |
> |  4 |
```

In case there are gaps between the ids or the minimum value is greater than 1 you can use a recursive CTE:

```
declare @maxid int = (select max(id) from sample);
with allids AS (
  select 1 id
  union all
  select id + 1 FROM allids where id + 1 <= @maxid
)
select s.id
from sample s inner join allids ss
on s.id >= ss.id
order by s.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f17a87094e0859be376212f3f5a8d8f6).

```
INSERT INTO Sample ( ID ) VALUES ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 5 ), ( 7 ), ( 9 );
```

Results:

```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> |  3 |
> |  3 |
> |  5 |
> |  5 |
> |  5 |
> |  5 |
> |  5 |
> |  7 |
> |  7 |
> |  7 |
> |  7 |
> |  7 |
> |  7 |
> |  7 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
> |  9 |
```

With this solution **you don't have to hardcode the ids** of the table (how many can they be?) and it will work even if you **add or delete ids**.